# Possible compiler bug for c4930

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

I just want to post this here to make sure I'm not missing something completely obvious (and will hence feel very silly).  This is a simplified version of some code I wrote.

```
template <int NDIM, typename T = int>
class COORD {
public:
    COORD(T dim0) { m_data[0] = dim0; }
private:
    T m_data[NDIM];
};

template <class COORD>
class NODE {
public:
    NODE(const COORD& c = COORD()) : m_coord(c) {}
private:
COORD m_coord;
};

int main()
{
    const int VAL = 10;
    NODE< COORD<1> > n( COORD<1>( VAL ) ); // warning c4930???
    NODE< COORD<1> > n2( COORD<1>( 10 ) );
    COORD<1> c( VAL );
    NODE< COORD<1> > n3( c );
    return 0;
}
```

The statement "NODE< COORD<1> > n( COORD<1>( VAL ) );" gives:

```
warning C4930: 'NODE<COORD> n(COORD<NDIM>)': prototyped function not called
(was a variable definition intended?)
    with
    [
        COORD=COORD<1>,
        NDIM=1
    ]
```

But, the decls for 'n2' and 'n3' compile fine.  This was with VC2008 & VC2010, I haven't tried VC2012 yet.  This block of code seems to compile fine on GCC 4.5.3.

Comment: Looks like the most vexing parse.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to take n as a function prototype. Probably the others too, just giving the warning only once. BTW: what's this: `const COORD& c = COORD()` shouldn't that be `const COORD& c = COORD<0>()` or something like that? And does COORD even have a default constructor if you already declared a non default one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's known as the ["most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). You may think you're creating a temporary object and using it to initialise a variable; but the compiler interprets it as a function declaration.
Specifically, `n` is a function returning `NODE<COORD<1>>`, taking an argument which is a pointer to a function taking an parameter called `VAL` (with a missing type specifier), and returning `COORD<1>`.

You can fix it by adding parentheses so it isn't interpreted as a function declaration:

```
NODE< COORD<1> > n( ( COORD<1>( VAL ) ) );
                    ^                 ^
```